# Form dropdown is giving me index and not the text

Tags: codeigniter

Can you help out a new learner of Codeigniter? for some reason my form dropdown is giving me the index as input->post. I just need the text selected.

**Model**

```
function get_items(){
        $this->db->select('item_name');
        $this->db->from('commissary_items');
        $query=$this->db->get();
        $result=$query->result();

            $item_names=array('-SELECT-');

            for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++){
                array_push($item_names,$result[$i]->item_name);
            }

            return $item_names;
        }
```

**View**

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row colbox">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                    <label for="item_name" class="control-label">Item</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
                    <?php
                    $attributes = 'class = "form-control" id = "item_name"';
                    echo form_dropdown('item_name',$item_name,set_value('item_name'),$attributes);?>
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('item_name'); ?></span>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function new_inventory(){
        $data['item_name']=$this->commissary_model->get_items();

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('date_added','Date Added','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('item_name','Item Name','callback_combo_check');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('quantity','Quantity','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('amount','Amount','required|numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','User Name');

        if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
            // $data="";
            $this->load->view('new_inventory_view',$data);
        }else{
            $data=array(
                    'date_added'=>@date('Y-m-d',@strtotime($this->input->post('date_added'))),
                    'item_name'=>$this->input->post('item_name'),
                    'quantity'=>$this->input->post('quantity'),
                    'amount'=>$this->input->post('amount'),
                    'username'=>$this->session->userdata('username')
                );
            $this->db->insert('add_inventory',$data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Item added to inventory.</div>');
            redirect('commissary/added_to_inventory');
        }
    }
```

Instead of the "text value" inside the form dropdown, I get the index 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 etc.... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That is how `<select>` options work - the `value` of the select option is returned.

If you want the text you will have to setup `$item_names` differently and have the `index` be the same as the text. Easily accomplished with a little restructuring in the model.

```
function get_items()
{
  $this->db->select('item_name');
  $this->db->from('commissary_items');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  $result = $query->result();

  $item_names = array();

  foreach($result as $item)
  {
    $item_names[$item->item_name] = $item->item_name;
  }

  return $item_names;
}
```